Почему от слова "бЕчёвка" происходят слова "бИчевать" и "(само)бИчевание"?
Бечёвка - плотная верёвка; в ранешние времена, очевидно, слово означало и плеть, которой могли поругать виновного. Оттуда и бичевание - избиение плетью. Так почему же в глаголе "бичевать" взялась И на месте Е?


БЕЧЁВКА, -и, род. мн. -вок, дат. -вкам, ж. Тонкая веревка. [Ерофей Кузьмич] покрутил руками вокруг ноги, будто завязывая бечевку от лаптя. Бубеннов, Белая береза.

БЕЧЁВКА. Искон. Уменьшит.-ласкат. от бечева < бечева тяга (ср. идти бечевою), где бечева — субстантивированное краткое прилагательное от тюрк. бек «веревка, шнур».
Происхождение слова бечёвка в этимологическом онлайн-словаре Шанского Н. М.

БИЧЕВА́ТЬ, -чу́ю, -чу́ешь; несов., перех. Сечь, хлестать плетью, кнутом. || перен. Резко изобличать, подвергать суровой критике. Бичевать пороки. □ Западноевропейская художественная литература дала замечательные произведения, бичующие капитализм. М. Калинин, О коммунистическом воспитании.

БИЧ. Такое слово, называющее разновидность кнута, есть почти во всех славянских языках, а образовано оно от глагола бити — так глагол бить звучал в старые времена.
Происхождение слова бич в этимологическом онлайн-словаре Крылова Г. А.
